# Get list of file names and their md5 hashes into text file

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal, zsh

I wrote this command to find all .txt file names and sort/deduplicate them then saving into a text file.

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec basename {} \; | sort | uniq - txtsort.txt
```

this way I get the file filled with the unique filenames

```
...
Empty.txt
...
```

How do I concatenate the files md5 hashes to their file names?

Like:

```
...
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e_Empty.txt
...
```

Comment: Beware: this command line won't handle filenames that contain newlines correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec bash -c "a=\$(basename {} | md5) ; mv {} \$(dirname {})/\$a\_\$(basename {}) " \;
```

This should do the trick.

**`find . -type f -name '*.txt'`** : Goes through all `.txt` files.

**`a=\$(basename {} | md5)`** : Stores md5 hash of current file's basename.

**`mv {} \$(dirname {})/\$a\_\$(basename {})`** : Renames the current file by adding `$a` i.e. the has separates by a `_`.

Comment: Maybe I should have explained myself better, I don't need to rename the files, I just need to store the list of found *md5_filename.txt* in a new text file (that then has to have its lines deduplicated and sorted)

Answer (score 0):

I found that using *md5 -r* answers my question (I don't really need the underscore in the name, it was just for aestetical purposes), so:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec md5 -r {} \; | sort | uniq - txtsort.txt
```

will do the trick.